# Асинхронный каунтер на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, асинхронность

Есть вот такой простой код на `javascript`:

```
function Counter () {
  this.count = 0;
  setInterval(() => this.count++, 1000);
}

var counter = new Counter();
```

Каждый раз когда я вызываю `counter`, я получаю значение, которое раз в 1 секунду увеличивается на 1.

Как написать аналогичную функцию в `python`?

Если я пробую что-то вроде:

```
def counter():
    counter = 0
    while counter < 1000:
        counter += 1
        sleep(1)
    return counter

c = counter()
```

То терминал занят и я не могу получить значение.

А если же так:

```
def counter():
    counter = 0
    while counter < 1000:
        counter += 1
        sleep(1)
        return counter

c = counter()
```

то `c` всегда равен 1

Comment: у вас три варианта, или `async` или `threading` или `process`, любым из этих способов можно запустить вашу функцию не блокируя основной процесс.

Comment: какой контекст (GUI, wsgi приложение, CLI скрипт)? Несколько [примеров кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279)

Comment: У вас функция return останавливает цикл, из-за чего тот заканчивается. Уберите таб на return. Чтобі терминал не бьіл занят уберите sleep, или поставьте число например 10. Если вам нужен просто каунтер а не секундомер уберите sleep.

Answer (score 6):

```
import time

def counter():
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        yield int(time.time() - start)


c = counter()

print(next(c))
time.sleep(2)
print(next(c))
time.sleep(1)
print(next(c))
```

Comment: ему нужен асинхронный аналог setInterval из javascript

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч может быть ему хватит счётчика отдающего при вызове количество секунд прошедших с момента его создания. По крайней мере javascript-код именно это и делает, если отбросить детали реализации.

Comment: стоит `time.monotonic()` вместо `time.time()`, чтобы counter не убывал. Если забыть про детали реализации, то простое замыкание (closure) можно использовать: `def counter(): start=time.monotonic()¶ return lambda: math.floor(time.monotonic() - start)`

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить целое количество секунд прошедших с момента создания counter:

```
import math
import time

def counter():
    return lambda start=time.monotonic(): math.floor(time.monotonic() - start)
```

Пример, где пауза между вызовами:

```
>>> c = counter()
>>> c()
1
>>> c()
4
>>> c()
8
```

Если хочется посмотреть как аналог setTimeout, setInterval из JavaScript в Питоне реализовать, то [примеры для разных библиотек: threading, tkinter, gtk, twisted, asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5177439/4279).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `itertools.count()`:

```
import itertools
counter = itertools.count()
```

Затем всякий раз, когда будет нужно следующее число, используйте

```
next(counter)
```

(например  `next_id = next(counter)`) так как `counter` просто *итератор*.

---

Примечание:

`itertools.count()` позволяет использовать *ключевые параметре* `start` и/или `step`, например `itertools.count(start=100, step=10)` выдает значения `100`, `110`, `120`, ...

Comment: в вопросе счётчик увеличивается каждую секунду, а не при каждом вызове.